# $x$ is distributed as Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, prove $\text{E}(\log(x+0.5)-\log\lambda)+0.02/\lambda>0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Let $x\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$, prove that for any $\lambda>0$,
$$f(\lambda)=\text{E}(\log(x+0.5)-\log\lambda)+0.02/\lambda>0.$$
In other words,
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\log(x+0.5)\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda}-\log\lambda+0.02/\lambda>0.$$
Here, $\log$ is the natural logarithm.

A possible approach: we have $f^{'}(\lambda)=\text{E}(\log(\frac{x+1.5}{x+0.5}))-1/\lambda-0.02/\lambda^2$ and $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}f(\lambda)=0$. Please try to avoid large-scale numerical computations as much as possible, because analyzing the error in floating-point arithmetic of computational code can be troublesome.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554787/what-are-the-mean-and-variance-of-the-log-of-a-random-variable

Comment: Crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/459239/ (but I think the OP belongs here at Mathematics.SE)